# Homology of complex affine space

Tags: algebraic-topology

Simple question. Perhaps *too* simple.

I have been looking around for a source for deriving the homology groups of ordinary complex space $\mathbb{C}^n$ for some time now, since I am uncertain of my own understanding, but I just cannot find a source anywhere. Whatever I google, I can only ever seem to find sources telling me what the homology groups of complex *projective* space, $\mathbb{C} \text{P}^n$, but nothing on plain old $\mathbb{C}^n$.

My *guess* is that you simply go about as follows. $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$, and so $\mathbb{C}^n \cong \mathbb{R}^{2n}$. Under this homeomorphism, a curve in $\mathbb{C}^n$ corresponds to a sheet in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, etc., etc., and so you can just jot down $H_i (\mathbb{C}^{n}) = H_{2i} (\mathbb{R}^{2n})$.

Is this understanding correct, or am I making some very trivial mistake?

Comment: $\mathbb C^n$ is connected and contractible, does that help?

Comment: Connected and contractible, thus homotopic to a point. Since homology (and cohomology) is homotopy invariant, complex affine space $\mathbb{C}^n$ has the same homology groups (and cohomology groups) of a single point. I truly am an idiot.

It certainly does help! Thank you, sir! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homology groups are topological invariants, it is irrelevant whether there are additional algebraic structures as on $\mathbb C^n$. So in fact, since $\mathbb C^n \approx \mathbb R^{2n}$, we get $H_i(\mathbb C^n) \approx H_i(\mathbb R^{2n})$. There is no dimension shift from $i$ to $2i$ here.

As Giulio comments, $\mathbb C^n$ is contractible, thus $H_i(\mathbb C^n) \approx H_i(*)$ for all $i$. Hence *coincidentally* $H_i(\mathbb C^n) \approx H_{2i}(\mathbb R^{2n})$.

PS. It is completely unclear what you want to say by "a curve in $\mathbb C^n$ corresponds to a sheet in $\mathbb R^{2n}$".

Comment: Yes, I was *incredibly* confused on that point, I must admit. See, I thought in terms of "a curve is a one-dimensional thing", and so since one complex dimension in $\mathbb{C}^n$ corresponds to two real dimensions in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, a curve in $\mathbb{C}^n$ would correspond to a sheet in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. However, of course, that is **not** a right understanding of what a curve in $\mathbb{C}^n$ is. A curve is simply a continuous mapping $[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n$, and so obviously there is no dimension shift. Thanks for the clarification!